# Why do I get " 'str' object is not callable" when appending variables to a list?

Tags: python, list, variables, append, callable

I have created a function which creates an empty list, and assigns a value from another list to a variable. Then the code is supposed to append the variable's value to the list each time the function is called. The function is placed in a while loop so it should continue to append. However after the first element is added, i get an error telling me that the string object is not callable. The code is below. I need this for a mock examination. Any ideas?:

```
def tracker():
    global tracker
    global trackerresult
    trackerresult = []
    tracker = opposite1[decider]
    trackerresult.append(tracker)
    print(trackerresult)
```

Results:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Timic\Downloads\Python Opposites Prorgam (1).py", line 47, in <module>
tracker()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please add a tag with the language (python, I think)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having a name conflict between the `tracker` global variable and the `tracker` function. When you run `def tracker(): ...`, it sets the variable `tracker` to a function object. When you then call the `tracker` function the first time, it modifies the global variable `tracker` to explicitly point to the result of `opposite1[decider]`, which is a string. The next attempt to call the `tracker` function fails beacuse the function has been overridden with a string.

Comment: Thanks for that, I managed to fix that error by changing the name of the function to track. But now a new logical error has been raised that doesn't append the variable `tracker`  to the list `trackerresult`. It just replaces it. Why?

Comment: @TimicNdoloka I do not understand what your problem is, but it is not related to this global-variable-shadowing problem and should be [asked seperately](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Thanks for that, Ill post a new question.